# Default start date and time coldfusion scheduled task

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-9

I have a scheduled task created using cfschduler tag in coldfusion which needs to be repeated in every hour. I am not using startdate and starttime attributes as it is optional. So If we create a task like this, what will be the default start date and time? When this task will start to execute?

Comment: First, not using startdate and starttime attributes seems remarkably unwise.  Second, why don't you simply try it and see?

Comment: `default startdate = creation date of task` and `default starttime = start of schedule tasks (server start)`? Why don't you just set the startttime?